# Select columns on day/month wise condition?

Tags: sql

I have a SQL table in the following format.

| mon_col | tue_col | wen_col | thu_col | fri_col | sat_col | sun_col |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| data | data | data | data | data | data | data |
| data | data | data | data | data | data | data |

This table has 7 columns which are created based on days in a week. I want to select the column based on the week day.

If day is Monday then it should only peak the Monday column.
`select mon_cal from table`

If day is Tuesday then then it should only peak the Tuesday column.

`select tue_cal from table`

So basic idea here is this query will execute everyday and day wise it should pickup the column. In other words for **Monday** it should only pickup **mon_col** and for **Tuesday** it should pickup **tue_col** and so on.

I tried the following query but it is giving the output as column name with null values.

```
DECLARE @column_name 'mon'

SELECT 
    product_name, 
    region, 
    CASE 
        WHEN  @column_name == 'mon' THEN mon_col 
    END AS selected_column
FROM 
    table
```

but it is not working it is giving else error.

Comment: You should use `=` and not `==`

Please let me know, if you still face issues after this change

Comment: You have tagged 4 rdbms , for sure the published code block won't syntax never mind work in mysql. What rdbms are you looking for a solution for? BTW that's a terrible table design

Comment: I've removed the conflicting tags, feel free to add the correct **one** back.

Answer (score 2):

You may need to unpivot the week columns (mon_col, tue_col, wed_col, thu_col, fri_col, sat_col, sun_col) in your case and then use WHERE condition to filter the weeks, see below my code example.

```
create table some_data
(
    product varchar(30),
    region varchar(30),
    mon_col varchar(30),
    tue_col varchar(30),
    wed_col varchar(30),
    thu_col varchar(30),
    fri_col varchar(30),
    sat_col varchar(30),
    sun_col varchar(30)
)

insert into some_data
values ('apple', 'USA', '1', '2', '3', '4','5','6','7'),
('banana', 'EUROPE', '100','200','300','400','500','600','700')

select product, region, valuex from some_data
unpivot
(valuex for WeekID in (mon_col, tue_col, wed_col, thu_col, fri_col, sat_col, sun_col))
as upt
where WeekID = 'mon_col'
```

Hope this helps

Comment: I want to select the columns only, Suppose today is monday query will select only monday column. the query should be as follows 

**Monday** : query will be `select mon_col from table`

**friday** : query will be `select fri_col from table`

Comment: Exactly, put the column name in where clause Where WeekID = 'column_name'.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of this question is as follows

```
DECLARE x  string DEFAULT FORMAT_DATE('%a', CURRENT_DATE());
with cte_name as (
                      select 
                      CASE 
                        WHEN x = 'Sun' THEN sun_col
                        WHEN x = 'Mon' THEN mon_col 
                        WHEN x = 'Tue' THEN tue_col 
                        WHEN x = 'Wed' THEN wed_col 
                        WHEN x = 'Thu' THEN thu_col 
                        WHEN x = 'Fri' THEN fri_col 
                        WHEN x = 'Sat' THEN sat_col 
                        ELSE NULL
                      END AS temp_col_name,  -- this will be the final alias of the column name
                      from table
)
select * from cte_name
```

In this query column will be selected as per week day and that column name will be rename as temp_col_name.

if query runs on sunday it will select **sun_col** and this column name treated or replace **temp_col_name**. so you need not to change anything in your other query.